# Do I need a visa for the UK before I apply for a Schengen visa?

Tags: uk, schengen, spain, tourist-visas

I live in India and want to travel for leisure for a total of 25 days to Spain and the UK.

I am planning to apply for single entry Schengen visa first. Will I need UK visit visa first or would a ticket from Spain to the UK be enough?

Answer (score 2):

The usual suggestion is to apply in **reverse** order of travel.

- You have to convince the UK that you will not overstay and that you will return to India. That can be difficult, since many people would like to immigrate into the UK, legally or illegally.
- You have to convince Spain that you will not overstay and that you will travel on. If you already *have* a UK visa at this point, explaining your onward travel is much easier.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar case, visiting London then going to France on a holiday. I applied for UK visa first before applying for schengen visa to French embassy. Everything went smooth. I was asked though in the french embassy to make sure i had proper visa when visiting London. I showed the lady that I already have the proper visit visa so that was it. I got both UK visa and Schengen visa on a holiday to France.